# Asp.net core 3.1 + Angular 10 use multiple razor (.cshtml ) pages

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, mastercard

I am creating a website using asp.net core 3.1 and angular 10.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

**Angular Routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  Shell.childRoutes([{ path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import('./about/about.module').then((m) => m.AboutModule) }]),
  Shell.childRoutes([{ path: 'fabric', loadChildren: () => import('./fabric/fabric.module').then((m) => m.FabricModule) }]),
  Shell.childRoutes([{ path: 'appointment', loadChildren: () => import('./appointment/appointment.module').then((m) => m.AppointmentModule) }]),
  Shell.childRoutes([{ path: 'customize', loadChildren: () => import('./customize/customize.module').then((m) => m.CustomizeModule) }]),
  Shell.childRoutes([{ path: 'invoice', canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard], loadChildren: () => import('./invoice/invoice.module').then((m) => m.InvoiceModule) }]),
  { path: 'myaccount', component: MyAccountComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
  { path: 'checkout', component: CheckoutComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix' },
  // Fallback when no prior route is matched
  { path: 'contact-us', component: ContactusComponent },
  { path: 'cart', component: CartComponent },
  { path: 'measurement', component: MeasurementComponent, canActivate : [AuthenticationGuard] },
  { path: 'faq', component: FaqComponent },
  { path: 'getsize', component: SizeComponent },
  { path: 'thankyou', component: ThankYouComponent },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

For payment security I want page to redirect to my controller action method and use a seperate .cshtml file for payment which is isolated from angular. For redirecting I am using `location.href` but it redirects back to home page.

**Controller action method to retun sepetate cshtml file**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Checkout()
        {
            var model = new PaymentCheckout();
            var apiBaseUri = _config.GetValue<string>("ApiBaseUri");
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
                //HTTP GET
                var responseTask = await client.GetAsync("someurl);
              
                if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentCheckout>(json);
                }
            }
            if (model == null) model = new PaymentCheckout();
            model.ApiBaseUri = apiBaseUri;
            return View(model);

        }
```

Locally I am able to redirect to this page. The issue is when I deploy the code on server.

Comment: What is The error message /or response you receive when you deploy the code on the server ?

Comment: hi @IbramReda there is no error message whenever i try to navigate ti that page it redirect back to home page

Comment: `For redirecting I am using location.href but it redirects back to home page` what's the URL you specified? an absolute URL or a relative URL?

Comment: absulute url only like `/account/checkout`